# Code works but too slow

Tags: python, numpy

How do i make this next piece of code run faster? 
I calculate the distance between a number of points first (no problem), but after that, i need to get the mean of the values all the points in one list that are closer than (in this case 20m), and if that 20 is small, this piece of code is fast, but otherwise, it is very slow, since i need the indices etc-
The next piece of code does exactly what i want, but it is extremely slow if i take 20 for value instead of for example 6 (because for 20, there are about 100 points close enough, while for 6, there are only 3 or 5 or so)

```
D = numpy.sqrt((xf[:,None] - xg[None,:])**2 + (yf[:,None] - yg[None,:])**2 + (zf[:,None] - zg[None,:])**2)
dumdic = {}
l1=[]
for i in range(len(xf)):
    dumdic[i] = D[i,:][D[i,:]<20]  # gets the values where the distance is small enough
    A=[]
    for j in range(len(dumdic[i])):
        A.append(G.epsilon[list(D[i,:]).index(dumdic[i][j])])  # for each point in that dummy dictionary, gets the index where i need to take the epsilon value, and than adds that right epsilon value to A
    l1.append(numpy.mean(numpy.array(A)))
a1 = numpy.array(l1)
```

G.epsilon is the array in which for each point we have a measurement value. So in that array i need to take (for each point in the other array) the mean for all points in this array that are close enough to that other point.

If you need more details, just ask

after the reply of @gregwittier, this is the better version: 
can anyone oneliner it yet?  (twoliner, since D=... takes one line)
would be more pythonic i guess if i dont have the l1=... and the recasting to numpy array, but the worst thing now is to kill that for-loop, by using an axis argument or so?

```
D = numpy.sqrt((xf[:,None] - xg[None,:])**2 + (yf[:,None] - yg[None,:])**2 + (zf[:,None] - zg[None,:])**2)
l1=[]
for i in range(len(xf)):
    l1.append(numpy.mean(G.epsilon[D[i,:]<20]))
a1 = numpy.array(l1)
```

Comment: @adrianratnapala i added some more info in the code. Personally i think the problem is the fact that i first use a dummy dictionary to get the points close enough, and than need to cast to a list to use .index, to get the indices where it is close enough. Too much casting from one thing to another to do what i want, it should be doable in one or two lines in an elegant way, but i dont know how

Comment: I updated my answer.  Basically the same as your update except I save a couple of lines using a list comprehension.

Comment: To remove the loop you can likely mask `G.epsilon` as `G.epsilon[D<20] = np.nan` and then take the mean by axis using [`nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nanmean.html) in scipy. The issue probably comes down to if you would need to copy `G.epsilon` or not. There is also the option of using masked arrays, info can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html). Your milage will vary depending if you need to copy or not and the time it takes to construct the masked array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
D2 = (xf[:,None] - xg[None,:])**2 + (yf[:,None] - yg[None,:])**2 + (zf[:,None] - zg[None,:])**2
near = D2 < 20**2
a1 = np.array([G.epsilon[near_row].mean() for near_row in near])
```

You could squeeze down another line by combining line 2 and 3.

```
D2 = (xf[:,None] - xg[None,:])**2 + (yf[:,None] - yg[None,:])**2 + (zf[:,None] - zg[None,:])**2
a1 = np.array([G.epsilon[near_row].mean() for near_row in D2 < 20**2])
```

Comment: a1 = G.epsilon[near]
ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension   But, you are thinking the right way, if i put that, in a for-loop, it will work i think

Comment: Ah.  I didn't catch that G.epsilon was 1-dimensional, so the columns of D and G.epsilon correspond, but you use the same G.epsilon for every row of D.  Anyway, I've edited my response.  I used a list comprehension instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your description in words seems different from what your example code actually does.  From the word description, I think you need something like

```
dist_sq = (xf-xg)**2 + (yf-yg)**2
near = (dist_sq < 20*20)
return dist_sq[near].mean()
```

I can't understand your example code, so I don't know how to match what it does.  Perhaps you will still need to iterate over one of the dimension (i.e. you might still need the outer `for` loop from your example).

Comment: added some more info on the code, to explain more (and my code does what it has to, just not fast enough)

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating the *all* distances between a set of points it might be a problem of complexity. As the set of points increases, the number of possible combinations increases dramatically.

[image]

Comment: true, but i think its my for-loop and the point where i cast to a list to than get the index, which screws it up,

Comment: @usethedeathstar Try timing each part of the code. To me it seems like a complexity problem.

Comment: even so, the increase in time is obviously a complexity problem, but if you have A*O(something), than you can mess with the A as well, which is what i wish to do